# How do you work with SESSION variable that is an object and also serialized?

Tags: session, object, serialization

I am trying to assign a value to an item within the serialized  object variable.  How do I go about that?  I have pasted below an excerpt of what the SESSION array looks like as key/value.

```
selected_region=18

delivery_region=18

cart=O:9:"cart":40:{s:16:"delivery_country";s:2:"US";s:16:"selected_country";s:2:"US";s:15:"delivery_region";s:2:"18";s:15:"selected_region";s:2:"18";s:24:"selected_shipping_method";s:9:"tablerate";s:24:"selected_shipping_option";s:10:"Table Rate";s:24:"selected_shipping_amount";d:8;s:6:"coupon";N;s:14:"tax_percentage";s:1:"0";s:9:"unique_id";s:40:"cdaa5a32e39b5470f21f43dd847e8cb1eb3d9327";s:6:"errors";a:0:{}s:9:"total_tax";i:0;s:13:"base_shipping";N;s:19:"total_item_shipping";N;s:14:"total_shipping";N;s:8:"subtotal";i:0;s:11:"total_price";N;s:13:"uses_shipping";N;s:13:"is_incomplete";b:1;s:10:"cart_items";a:0:{}s:9:"cart_item";O:14:"cart_item":34:
```

I am trying to assign say "selected_shipping_amount" to another value. How can I reach into that and assign it?

Thanks...

Answer (score 1):

I think your only option is to unserialize it, assign the value and then serialize it again.

Comment: ok what is needed to unserialize it and serialize it again and then pass it back to the session?

Comment: $array = unserialize($var);
$array["selected_shipping_amount"] = 9000;
$var = serialize($array);

Comment: That gave me an error.. Fatal error: Cannot use object of type cart as array in...